# Pandas DataReader Error = Length mismatch: Expected axis has 8 elements, new values have 7 elements

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

When I want to import data from the St.Louis Fed, Python gives me an error like this:

> Length mismatch: Expected axis has 8 elements, new values have 7 elements.

I can solve this error by deleting the last column of the dataFrame, but I need it. What should I do?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
import pandas as pd
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 1)
df = pdr.DataReader(
    [
        "WFRBSB50215",
        "WFRBST01134",
        "WFRBST01122",
        "WFRBSN09139",
        "WFRBSB50189",
        "WFRBST01110",
        "WFRBSB50191",
        "WFRBSN09148",
    ],
    "fred",
    start,
    end,
)
df.columns = [
    "Share of Total Net Worth Held by the Bottom 50% (1st to 50th Wealth Percentiles)",
    "Share of Total Net Worth Held by the Top 1% (99th to 100th Wealth Percentiles)",
    "Share of Corporate Equities and Mutual Fund Shares Helb By Top1%(99th to 100th Wealth Percentiles)",
    "Share of Financial Assets Held by the 90th to 99th Wealth Percentiles",
    "Share of Total Assets Held by the Bottom 50% (1st to 50th Wealth Percentiles)",
    "Share of Real Estate Held by the Top 1% (99th to 100th Wealth Percentiles)",
    "Share of Real Estate Held by the Bottom %50(1st to 50th Wealth Percentiles)"
    "Share of Mortgages Held by the 90th to 99th Wealth Percentiles",
]
ax = df.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(12, 12), linewidth=3.5, colormap="summer")
plt.xlabel("Date")
ax[
    0,
].set_title("Share of Total Net Worth Held by the Bottom 50%")
ax[
    0,
].set_ylabel("Percent of Aggregate")
ax[
    1,
].set_title("Share of Total Net Worth Held by the Top 1%")
ax[
    1,
].set_ylabel("Percent of Aggregate")
ax[
    2,
].set_title("Share of Corporate Equities and Mutual Fund Shares Helb By Top 1%")
ax[
    2,
].set_ylabel("Percent of Aggregate")
ax[
    3,
].set_title("Share of Financial Assets Held by the 90th to 99th Wealth Percentiles")
ax[
    3,
].set_ylabel("Percent of Aggregate")
ax[
    4,
].set_title("Share of Total Assets Held by the Bottom 50% ")
ax[
    4,
].set_ylabel("Percent of Aggregate")
ax[
    5,
].set_title("Share of Real Estate Held by the Top 1%")
ax[
    5,
].set_ylabel("Percent of Aggregate")
ax[
    6,
].set_title("Share of Real Estate Held by the Bottom %50")
ax[
    6,
].set_ylabel("Percent of Aggregate")
ax[
    7,
].set_title("Share of Mortgages Held by the 90th to 99th Wealth Percentiles")
ax[
    7,
].set_ylabel("Percent of Aggregate")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a comma after the second to last item in the new `df.columns`.

Without it, the strings on separate lines come together, totaling 7 elements instead of the expected 8.

Comment: you have better eyes than eagles, thank you very much:))